# How to get the ReactJS element inside componentDidMount()?

Tags: reactjs

I have 4 instances of a certain React-class. After `componentDidMount()` I want to store the y-position of each instance.

How can I address the rendered element? I cannot use classname, because I have 4 elements of the same class with different positions.

My ReactJS component:

```
const Col = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        //here address the actual rendered col-instance
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='col'>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Just trying to understand the question more. Are you trying to store the y-position of each React component instance to use later? Also does the y-position of each of these elements change after mounting?

Comment: I need to store it, it won't change. Maybe I can use this.ref ?

Comment: Could you explain a little further what you are trying to achieve? Where do you want to store what? How do you want to access the stored values and from where?

Comment: @FabianSchultz in the main-container there will be 4 <Col> -Elements, I want to store the y-pos of each <Col> in an array inside the Col-React-Class.

Comment: So every `Col` element stores the `y` values of all `Col` elements?

Answer (score 14):

Use [refs](http://chenglou.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-attribute).

First, hook-up a `ref` attribute on each of your JSX cols element. Then, use this `ref`, inside the `componentDidMount` method, to access the component's DOM node (the actual HTMLElement). Finally, get element's position / offset or anything else that you need.

```
const Col = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        // this.refs.col1 is the actual DOM element,
        // so you can access it's position / offset or whatever
        const offsetTop = this.refs.col1.offsetTop;
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col" ref="col1">
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

PS: I am not sure what do you mean by saying element `y` position. Anyways, once you know how to get the DOM element (`this.refs.col1`), you can then use [javascript to retrieve the position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element) you need.

Comment: It was a good solution for older API of React.js.  From https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html: "We advise against it because string refs have some issues, are considered legacy, and are likely to be removed in one of the future releases. "   With new API here the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42242146/react-how-to-access-the-dom-element-in-my-render-function-from-the-same-compone